# SQL query for data analytics through CTE to understand trends of dairy shipping business. What kind of packaging, top moving items, most busy area

Tags: sql, analytics, common-table-expression, teradata-sql-assistant

I am able to grab all records with this Query and want to break it down using CTE for simple DA in understanding the volume of packaging we use per month, which SKUs move most per month,
and volume by location.  If I do this for the year 2021 I get timed out at 30 minutes with over 15 million records. I want to be learn how to answer these questions using SQL

```
SELECT
SKU,
,boxsize
,month
,CASE WHEN aisle IN ('700','781') THEN 'Dairy' ELSE 'FrozenDairy' END AS Location

FROM production_table 

JOIN date_table t2
    ON to_date(create_tstamp_local) = t2.date
    
JOIN aisle_info t3
    ON sku= t3.sku
    
JOIN orders_table t4
  ON delivery_number =t4.delivery_num
  
WHERE order_status = 'shipped'
AND filling_rsc = 'IL01'
AND t3.aisle_num IN ('780','781','682','683','684','685','686','687','688','689','690','692')
AND t2.year = 2021
AND t4.shipped = 'F'
```

Result:

| SKU | boxsize | month | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1045678 | 12x12x12 | 1 | 55 |
| 1045678 | 6x6x6 | 2 | 53 |
| 5796678 | 12x12x12 | 1 | 55 |
| 1045678 | 12x12x12 | 1 | 55 |

Expected table results:

TABLE 1: Packaging analysis of distinct box size counts by SKU per month

| SKU | boxsize | BoxSizeCount | month | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1045678 | 12x12x12 | 1,000,000 | 1 | 55 |
| 1045678 | 6x6x6 | 1,000,000 | 1 | 55 |
| 1045678 | 12x12x12 | 200,000 | 2 | 55 |
| 1045678 | 6x6x6 | 200,000 | 2 | 55 |
| 5796678 | 12x12x12 | 100,000 | 3 | 53 |
| 1045678 | 12x12x12 | 100,000 | 3 | 55 |

TABLE 2: SKU analysis of distinct box size counts by SKU per month

| SKU | SKUCount | month | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1045678 | 1,500,000 | 1 | 55 |
| 9045672 | 1,000,000 | 1 | 55 |
| 1032618 | 220,000 | 1 | 55 |
| 1045673 | 245,000 | 1 | 55 |
| 5796678 | 175,000 | 2 | 53 |
| 1031045678 | 100,039 | 2 | 53 |

I can export these two tables to use for the third Location analysis.

Answer (score 0):

```
SKU,
,boxsize
,month
,CASE WHEN aisle IN ('700','781') THEN 'Dairy' ELSE 'FrozenDairy' END AS Location
**,COUNT(1) AS record_count**

FROM production_table 

JOIN date_table t2
    ON to_date(create_tstamp_local) = t2.date
    
JOIN aisle_info t3
    ON sku= t3.sku
    
JOIN orders_table t4
  ON delivery_number =t4.delivery_num
  
WHERE order_status = 'shipped'
AND filling_rsc = 'IL01'
AND t3.aisle_num IN ('780','781','682','683','684','685','686','687','688','689','690','692')
AND t2.year = 2021
AND t4.shipped = 'F'

**GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7**`
```